# AsynchronousSocketChannel.write ensures TCP ACK?

Tags: nio

Question regarding [AsynchronousSocketChannel.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler)) method

```
public final <A> void write(ByteBuffer src,
             A attachment,
             CompletionHandler<Integer,? super A> handler)
```

**Does this method guarantee ACK is received before the `handler` is fired?**

Or it just ensures the `ByteBuffer` is delivered to network driver of local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. It ensures that the data has been transferred into the socket send buffer. From there it goes asynchronously to the NIC and from there to the network.